# Join is working in pgAdmin but not in DB Manager

Tags: postgis, dbmanager

I have two tables `tbl1` and `tbl2` without geometries which I'm trying to join (and later join result to a table with geometries when I get the first join to work):

[image: Selects from pgAdmin]

Simply:

```
select * from tbl1
left join tbl2
on tbl1.status_id = tbl2.status_id
```

Is working in [`pgAdmin`](https://www.pgadmin.org/):

[image: Select join from pgAdmin]

But not in ([QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/fr/site/)) DB manager:

[image: Select join from QGIS]

It is driving me crazy. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also checked because I'm curious, and indeed, I encountered the same error!

In [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/fr/site/) DB Manager, nothing came out of an exact same [`pgAdmin`](https://www.pgadmin.org/) `join` command!

In your DB Manager, you can try to "Create a view".

This has a little more verbosity; in my case, there was an error that was silently passed while simply executing the query:

```
ERROR:  column "ogc_fid" specified more than once
```

Apparently, [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/fr/site/) needs every column from both tables to have different names (?)

Even if from your screenshots it doesn't seem to be the case for you, it's worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

As figured out by @s.k having the same column names in two tables seem to be causing DB manager to fail (for me without any error messages)

This Query is working, annoying though:

```
select * from (
(select "status_id" as tbl1_id, "somedate" from "tbl1") sub1
left join 
(select "status_id" as tbl2_id, "data" from "tbl2") sub2
on sub1."tbl1_id" = sub2."tbl2_id")
```

I cant do that for 50+ tables, guess I'll have to use pgAdmin.